# Calling another method from within a GCD queue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

If I do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
[self someMethod];
 });
```

And `someMethod` is this:

```
-(void)someMethod{
  //doing stuff with no mention of GCD
 }
```

Will `someMethod` run inside the dispatch queue, or will that queue wait for `someMethod` to run on the main thread, since `someMethod` does not itself dispatch anything to other queues?

Comment: `someMethod` won't run on the main thread, and won't wait for anything  on the main thread to finish either. It will run in a different thread which has a **high** priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods are executed on the thread or queue from which they are invoked. So, if you wanted to update UI after processing data on a background queue, you'd need to explicitly execute your UI update on the main thread.

For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
   [self someMethod];
});

- (void) someMethod{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update UI here
    });
}
```